# Loading JavaScript file from a File into WebEngine correctly

Tags: java, javascript, javafx

What's the proper way to read, say, "example.js" file into `WebEngine` so that `executeScript()` understands it? I am just learning JavaScript, and I am getting all kinds of errors that are possibly caused by `\n \r \t` characters? I realize "all kinds of errors" is a bit vague, but I really am getting all kinds of different errors, depending if I, say, remove a comment in the JavaScript-file.

If I copy and paste the whole file as a String for `executeScript()`, all is fine. So I guess it's the control characters that cause these errors.. but I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Can you post your javascript file

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why, but Files.readAllLines() and Scanner both resulted in JavaScript Syntax errors... no matter if I tried to "mess" with newlines manually. With this method everything works just fine.

```
private static String readUrl(URL url) throws IOException {
        BufferedInputStream in = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

            baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            final byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            int count;
            while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
                baos.write(data, 0, count);
            }
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
        }
        return baos.toString("UTF-8");
    }
```